# Use picocom - sending request

Tags: linux, serial-port, arduino

I'm sorry, but I don't understand how use picocom to send a request/command to the device.
Official doc: http://linux.die.net/man/8/picocom

I want to be IN the OS I reach, I connect to an Arduino YUN using linux OS inside and I want to be root on it, it's probably easy, I'm already connected but I don't understand what I have to do!

```
vado@ubuntu:~$ picocom -b 115200 /dev/ttyACM0
picocom v1.4

port is        : /dev/ttyACM0
flowcontrol    : none
baudrate is    : 115200
parity is      : none
databits are   : 8
escape is      : C-a
noinit is      : no
noreset is     : no
nolock is      : no
send_cmd is    : ascii_xfr -s -v -l10
receive_cmd is : rz -vv

Terminal ready
```

Terminal ready and I can do nothing, I can't entering command line or whatever. I tried to do ce escape think with C-a but I don't understand at all how enter C-a...

Need help, please.
Thank you.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

With picocom you can communicate to a serial device. 
Once you open it, you have something similar to the arduino serial monitor but every character you type is directly sent to the arduino.
You can use putty if you don't like picocom commands.

The escape commands C-a means: <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

To quit picocom, first press <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> followed by a regular <kbd>x</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you, I read your answer but didn't answered before now. It's not working, I mean my Arduino is not responding at all, using picocom, putty, serial and ethernet, I get nothing on the console. I think linux is dead, I tried to figure it out the last two weeks but nobody knows what's going on, I'll send it back. Thanks.

Comment: if the arduino doesn't respond on anything, than indeed the linux is dead.

Comment: It's such a bother when the linux dies.

Answer (score 24):

Press ctrl button and then without releasing it press a and then q. It will exit the picocom application.

Answer (score 14):

I found I have to do it this way. Hold "Ctrl" and "a". Then release. Then hold "Ctrl" and "x".

Comment: this is correct answer

Answer (score 2):

To quit while running in tmux, users who use Ctrl-a as a prefix.

```
C-a, a, C-x
```

Ctrl-a and release it. One more 'a' and release it. Ctrl-x and then it will quit.

Comment: I tried this also for picocom running inside minicom (From my Mac there is a minicom session to RasPi and on RasPi is a picocom session to a modem). But the suggested commands are not working here...

Answer (score 2):

You can type Ctrl+A, followed by Ctrl+ H to see the available commands
[Picocom commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9Krw.png)

```
*** Picocom commands (all prefixed by [C-a])

*** [C-x] : Exit picocom
*** [C-q] : Exit without reseting serial port
*** [C-b] : Set baudrate
*** [C-u] : Increase baudrate (baud-up)
*** [C-d] : Decrease baudrate (baud-down)
*** [C-i] : Change number of databits
*** [C-j] : Change number of stopbits
*** [C-f] : Change flow-control mode
*** [C-y] : Change parity mode
*** [C-p] : Pulse DTR
*** [C-t] : Toggle DTR
*** [C-g] : Toggle RTS
*** [C-|] : Send break
*** [C-c] : Toggle local echo
*** [C-w] : Write hex
*** [C-s] : Send file
*** [C-r] : Receive file
*** [C-v] : Show port settings
*** [C-h] : Show this message
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31404657)

Answer (score 1):

After the terminal is ready, you will need to hold "ctrl+a" then press "c" to enable local echo. It will help you to see the commands you are sending and also the response

Answer (score 1):

`CTRL`+`SHFT`+`A` and then `CTRL`+`SHFT`+`X` works for me on picocom v2.2